# jQuery code after ajax runs before ajax is completed

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$("form#go").submit(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var btn = $this.find("button");
    btn.text("Searching").attr('disabled','disabled');
    $.ajax({
        url:
        type:
        data:
        dataType:
                    success:function(result){
             //code....
                    }
    });
    btn.text("Go").removeAttr('disabled');

    return false;
});
```

This is my code structure. The problem is `btn.text("Go!").removeAttr('disabled');` runs immediately and I can't see the disabled button and the change of button text , although the ajax part takes 500ms to finish.

If I change the last part to

```
setTimeout(function () {
     btn.text("Go").removeAttr('disabled');
 }, 1000);
```

Then I can see the change for 1 second, so I guess my code works. But I have no idea why it runs before the `ajax` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call it in ajax success call back, as ajax call is async so your code will get executed before ajax call completes:

```
$.ajax({

............
...........
success: function()
{
setTimeout(function () {
     btn.text("Go").removeAttr('disabled');
 }, 1000);
}

});
```

Comment: I have `success:function(){}` in my `ajax` part

Comment: so you need to write that code in success function not outside ajax call if it is to be executed after ajax call

Answer (score 1):

You need to add that code as a call back in the complete or done function of the ajax call

[Read more about it here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Here's an example from the link I posted

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});
```

Comment: I have `success:function(){}` in my ajax part

Comment: @Harrison, I saw that.  Since you had the code after the ajax call, I assumed you wanted it to run regardless of success or failure, which is why I suggested complete and done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a success function!

Like this:

```
$("form#go").submit(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var btn = $this.find("button");
    btn.text("Searching").attr('disabled','disabled');
    $.ajax({
        //codes......
        success:function(){
            btn.text("Go").removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });


    return false;
});
```

Comment: I have `success:function(){}` in my ajax part

Comment: So, just like mentioned above you have to put it into the success function like in my example.

Answer (score 0):

By default jQuery Ajax calls are asynchronous. So to make synchronous Ajax call, you can use option **async:false** in your ajax call. Below is the simple example:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'url',
  data: {},
  type: 'POST',
  async: false,
  //and any other options you want to use
}).success(function(data) {
  //success code
}).error(function(data) {
  //error handling
});
```

You can refer this page for more details - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/