# Checking if email already exist or not using javascript and Asp.net method

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webmethod

I am checking that if email exist or not using javascript , But it is firing "Email already exist" every time even if email does not already exist. Code is given below :

**Javascript code :**

```
 function chkemailExist(source, args) {
        var exists;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Register.aspx/DoesUserExist",
            data: "{'emailid': '" + args.Value + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (result) {
                exists = result.d;

            }
        });
        args.IsValid = exists;
        if (!exists) {
            var message="Email already exist for" + args.Value + ". ";
            alert(message);
        }
        else { document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_CustomValidator1').innerHTML = ""; }
    }
```

**Web Method :**

```
   [WebMethod]
   public static bool DoesUserExist(string emailid)

{
    Boolean flg = true;
    //Int32 cntchk = 0;
    PAL_Register reg = new PAL_Register();
    BAL_Register bal_reg = new BAL_Register();
    reg.UserName = emailid;
    flg = bal_reg.checkusername(reg);
    return flg;
}
```

Please help to get correct my code so it fire alert for exist email only when email already exist in actual.

Comment: Are you sure this is right? `if (!exists)`

Comment: Asynchronous call problem here?

Comment: @AntP - Yes.. then also please let me know if any my mistake.

Comment: AJAX problems aside, your logic says "if the user doesn't exist, tell them the user already exists." You don't see an issue there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery code after ajax runs before ajax is completed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24140140/jquery-code-after-ajax-runs-before-ajax-is-completed)

Answer (score 2):

AJAX is **asynchronous** - you're trying to do logic on a variable that doesn't exist yet because the call is in progress. Do your work in the callback!

```
 function chkemailExist(source, args) {
    var exists;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Register.aspx/DoesUserExist",
        data: "{'emailid': '" + args.Value + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {
            exists = result.d;
            args.IsValid = exists;
            if (!exists) {
                var message="Although you indicated you're a new customer, an account already exists for " + args.Value + ". ";
                alert(message);
            }
            else { 
                document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_CustomValidator1').innerHTML = "";
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: I replaced script now it is not giving alert for any. Means it is not giving alert when email already exist.:(

Comment: @rahulbhatt -- Do you get the correct response from your server?

Comment: Yes , But it is not alerting now.

Answer (score 0):

Comments might be true but I have the feeling that there's another problem anyway : a non-empty string always evaluates to true in javascript, and as the response from your server is not typed (if I'm not mistaken), it will always evaluate to `true` was the string "true" or "false" ... you should test the string value or return an empty string for `false`.

cfr [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kfmcb5mk/)